# Restrict maximum pod replica count on k8s node

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have a k8s cluster with 2 node groups (worker group and task runner group for heavy tasks).

I have a deployment with N pod replicas and I want to assign a maximum of 2 replicas per node.

I found a way to restrict replicas count to 1 by describing Anti Affinity rules for pods and tried to add Topology Spread Constraints with the MaxSkew parameter, but this didn't work.

Is there any way to restrict the maximum pod replica count per node?

Answer (score 0):

The key is to use `topologyKey`.

```yaml
affinity:
    podAntiAffinity:
      preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - podAffinityTerm:
          labelSelector:
            matchLabels:
              name: deployment-name
          topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
        weight: 100
```

---

A bit about `topologyKey`:

> In principle, the topologyKey can be any allowed label key with the following exceptions for performance and security reasons:
>
> For Pod affinity and anti-affinity, an empty topologyKey field is not allowed in both requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution and preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution.
>
> For requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution Pod anti-affinity rules, the admission controller LimitPodHardAntiAffinityTopology limits topologyKey to kubernetes.io/hostname.
>
> You can modify or disable the admission controller if you want to allow custom topologies.

---

#### Pod Topology Spread Constraints

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-topology-spread-constraints/

> `topologyKey` is the key of node labels.
> If two Nodes are labelled with this key and have identical values for that label, the scheduler treats both Nodes as being in the same topology.
> **The scheduler tries to place a balanced number of Pods into each topology domain.**

Comment: It's kind of works, but sometimes, when i create new deployment with referenced anti affinity rule, scheduler may assign more than two pods ln the same node. Current nodes in target group is 4, replicas number in deployment manifest: 8. Expected behavior: assigning no more than 2 pod replicas on every node.